# Power Query - Creating a History table from a Part Change Register

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, ms-word, powerquery

Hoping a Power Query Ninja might assist in solving this…

Reference attachment, I have 2 tables the first [ChangeRegTBL] is a dynamic table (which currently is some 7500+ lines long) which appends changes we've implemented into a build/assembly line.  In certain instances, those part number changes are changed again into a new number once again…and in some instances 7-8 times!.

What I'm after is a table (shown in ref attachment as [ ChangeHistTBL] ) which lists a history of every Part Old and what its superseded Part New is and if changed more than once a count and finally a history table summarising Date, Change Request and Part Detail.

Now I've had multiple goes with many merges etc…but it's just messy, slow and certainly doesn't deal with a dynamic table.

Trying to get to grips with the List. Accumulate function…as I feel the solution is within this

Cheers

[image]

Ok, I can't seem to add a workbook as an attachment, but can send this if required!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `List.Generate` to generate a part history for each part number as shown in your table, and `List.PositionOf` to find the `New Part` in the `Old Part` column for the next history step.

The algorithm does a series of lookups of New Part in the Old Part column, and then adds the corresponding history entry to the Part History list associated with the Old Part.

Not sure if this approach will be faster, but should be dynamic:

See comments in the code. Ask if something not clear

**M code**
***edited to change the Part New column to last in the list***
***Edited to start the List.Generate loop at the current row***
***Edited to eliminate the endless loop when original part number is re-used***

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\OneDrive\Documents\ChangeReg.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Index", Int64.Type}, {"Change Ref", type text}, {"Part Old", type text}, {"Part New", type text}, {"Part Description", type text}}),

 //Create Part History column
     ph = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "hist", each 
            let 
                cr = Text.Split([Change Ref]," ")
            in  cr{1} & "_" & [Part New] & "_" & cr{0} & "_" & [Part Description]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(ph,{"Change Ref", "Part Description"}),

//create list of part histories and successor part number
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "phList", each 
    let 
        //start search at current row
        newPart = List.RemoveFirstN(ph[Part New],[Index]),
        oldPart = List.RemoveFirstN(ph[Part Old],[Index]),
        partHist = List.RemoveFirstN(ph[hist],[Index]),
        index = List.RemoveFirstN(ph[Index],[Index]),
        trace = List.Generate(()=> [newP=newPart{0}, hist=partHist{0}, idx= index{0}],
                        each [idx] <> null,
                        each 
                            let 
                                //note that if [newP] not found then List.PositionOf => -1
                                i = List.PositionOf(oldPart,[newP])
                            in  if i > index{0} then 
                                    [newP = newPart{List.PositionOf(oldPart,[newP])},
                                     hist = partHist{List.PositionOf(oldPart,[newP])},
                                     idx = index{List.PositionOf(oldPart,[newP])}]
                                else 
                                    [idx=null])
    in 
        trace),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Part New", "hist"}),

//Add last part number in the sequence
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Part New", each List.Last([phList])[newP]),

//count number of times the part number changed
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Superceded Count", each List.Count([phList])),

//concatenate history of all the changes in the part numbers
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Part History", each List.Accumulate([phList],"",
        (state,current)=> if state = "" then current[hist] else state & "#(lf)" & current[hist])),

    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"phList"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

**Source**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Ron, many thanks for looking at this!!! I'm going to have a play and digest the code.

Comment: I've spotted something. Ref Index 0 for example the Part New field would should show JT768768 (the latest superseded part no.) not JJ24451. Similarly for index 4 would be TT35647.  I'm having a go myself as well...I've so much to learn!

Comment: @MrBagins I missed that.  I thought Part New didn't change from the Original data.  But that is easily changed in the code.

Comment: @MrBagins Edited to create a new `Part New` column now showing the last Part in the chain

Comment: That works great. Now I've applied it to a table with a couple of hundred records and it just slows down and never completes the table. I've tried Table.Buffer and have gone through the data to see what's maybe throwing off. Can I create a larger table to try maybe? I'm still testing my end to see what i can do

Comment: @MrBagins Can you convert your large table to a CSV, and then upload it to some public sharing site (eg OneDrive, DropBox, Drive, etc)? If so, post a link here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks again. I've found that there are instances where we've gone back to the previous part number! When i've removed these it works! Could there be a way of the loops only going from current index and greater?

Comment: @MrBagins Would be useful to have a sample (as Text) that demonstrates the problem. Perhaps you could upload a CSV file that shows that problem (along with the slowness) and post a link here.  So far as starting the `List.Generate` look at the current row, we can do that by truncating the `newPart, oldPart, partHist` lists by removing `FirstN` entries, where `N` is the value in the `Index` column you've fortuitously provided as zero-based in your original table.  See edited code.

Comment: Hi Ron, the slowness was associated to the previous point of part being re-instated. I think that caused a endless loop! I'm going to play with the new code...Ron you are a star, I need to buy you many many beers!

Comment: I’ve added a sample https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlekpb2dj5fgq80/ChangeReg.csv?dl=0

Comment: @MrBagins There is an issue with your downloaded file in that the List creation for the first five rows repeats multiple times.  Seems to be OK for row 6  and later. Going out of town this weekend so won't have time to troubleshoot until next week.  Have also developed a possibly more efficient method of generating the list.

Comment: Those rows are what i meant reference the prt number changing then later in the table changing back to the original value. I’ve been breaking down your code and tying to slowly understand how it functions. Looking forward to seeing your other methods !  Thanks again Ron

Comment: @MrBagins Change the `List.Generate` "loop terminate" test to ensure the row being tested is always after the current row. (If a part number gets re-used, the test will fail and terminate the loop). This also seems to work well with your CSV file.  Let me know.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough Ron! Off to play and have a jolly good go at understanding the M Code

Comment: Ron, it works perfectly!! You are an absolute credit to Stack Overflow. Thank you

Comment: Ron, I've added some List.Buffers to your code as it was slow, as the table has a few merges before the final table is created. Do you think this is the best method? it seems to work ok. 
        //start search at current row
        newPart = List.Buffer(List.RemoveFirstN(ph[Part New],[Index])),
        oldPart =  List.Buffer(List.RemoveFirstN(ph[Part Old],[Index])),
        partHist =  List.Buffer(List.RemoveFirstN(ph[hist],[Index])),
        index =  List.Buffer(List.RemoveFirstN(ph[Index],[Index])),

Comment: @MrBagins Does it help?  Is that where the slow-down is?  Buffering Lists (or Tables) sometimes helps and sometimes doesn't make much difference.  In PowerBI desktop you can analyze the steps, and see which is taking the longest. That's sometimes helpful.  When I tried List.Buffer on your data set, it didn't seem to make much difference. I'd say if it helps, use it; if not, you'll need to figure out where the slow down is coming from, and work on that.